# merging duplicates and merge into rows for excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I wish to do the following but not sure how to do it...Can help on this?

Original

```
Column1   Column2
TitleA       123
TitleA       345
TitleB       888
TitleC       567
TitleC       789
```

After

```
Column1   Column2
TitleA       123   345
TitleB       888
TitleC       567   789
```

Appreciate if anyone can help to advise :)

Comment: you could probably build a vba macro to do so. We can help you *correcting* the code provided you made a first try

Comment: Are you trying to combine the numbers into 1 column or into multiple columns? ie, Are `345` & `789` in `Column2` or `Column3`?

Comment: i see what i can do and research on the vba macro...thx alot...345 & 789 are for column2 and column3 ...more columns needed if duplcate values for column1

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this old macro I have and try to customize it to fit your needs, any guidance you need, just ask.

```
Sub ConcatenateAcrossColumns()

Dim data, numrows As Long, result, i As Long, n As Long

'turn off screen update
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

'check if the data on the sheet start where the code expects it
If Range("a1") = "" Then Exit Sub

'define data range
With Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)

    'sort data range by A1
    .Sort key1:=Range("a1"), Header:=xlNo
    'take data to array
    data = .Value
    'setting variable value equal to number of rows in array
    numrows = UBound(data)
    'creating result array
    ReDim result(1 To numrows, 1 To 1)

    'start loop from 1 row to the last row of array
    For i = 1 To numrows
    'taking first animal name to a variable
    temp = data(i, 1)
    'put number of the animal to result array
    result(i, 1) = result(i, 1) & data(i, 2)
    'loop until value of temp not equals current animal - ex.: cat <> dog
    For n = i + 1 To numrows
        'if cat = cat write it's corresponding value from the second column to result array
        If data(n, 1) = temp Then result(i, 1) = result(i, 1) & "," & data(n, 2) Else Exit For

    Next
    'going 1 row backward
    i = n - 1

    Next
    'output result array to the sheet
    .Offset(, 2).Resize(, 1) = result

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! will try and let you know :)